# ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage codename one not working

Tags: codenameone

```
ImageDownloadService.createImageToStorage(PhotoUrl, 
                                          mb.getIconComponent(),
                                          "News_" + (String)entry.get("Id")+".png", 
                                          new Dimension(imageWidth,imageHeight));
```

in my createEntry function return MultiButton, but it not working! My button don't have icon, what wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you open the network manager to see what happened?

You can use URLImage since you already know the dimension of the image and its technically superior http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/03/image-from-url-made-easy.html